# Entity Framework configuration file compilation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, onion-architecture

I am using Entity Framework and an onion architecture to make my website maintainable and persistent. Now as I followed a particular onion architecture example, I ended up with:

1. Domain (entities, and domain interfaces)
2. Repository (IRepo, and Repo etc...)
3. Service (established a link between UI and Repo, to respect SoC (if I got it correctly) etc ...)
4. UI (in my case an MVC project)

Now I have separated my Entity Framework entities from my context. Entities go in the **domain** whereas the context goes in the **repository**. This means that when I enabled migrations, the configuration.cs file has been added  to migrations folder in `Domain` but now since `Domain` has no dependencies, I have no access to my context (it is in a higher layer, therefore that would violate onion architecture rules (dependencies can't go outwards)).

- Should I move my migrations folder to repository ?
- Should I `enable-migrations` in repository ?
- My `configuration.cs` file is very thin, is it mandatory to keep it (it does keep `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to false which makes me doubt this, seems like something lazy to do but who knows)?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain should be with as few dependencies as possible, so you can:

- Create a new project and move there only the context and `enable-migrations` on this project. By doing this you can decouple the repositories from the context.
- Leave as is, and use `enable-migrations` in the repository project, just as you said.

I'm using the first choice in my onion-architecture project.

Comment: Alright thanks, so I guess context will be in a project between `Domain` and `Repository`?

Comment: Yes, that's one option. I'm using it like this.